# Performance in LAMP: Filesystem vs. Database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, filesystems

I need to design a website which has friendly URLs configurable by some specific users. They must be in a database to manage them (which user created it, which module and data must load, etc.), and they must have some permissions system (view, actions, etc.).

The question is: It would have better performance if I created a php file for each path (like /section/subsection/index.php) to be loaded directly by Apache, it would be better if I check every query in the database, or it depends of the kind of page?

There would be 3 kind of pages:
- Mostly static (once created won't need to connect with database)
- Periodically updated (I can delete that pages when they are not updated)
- Mostly dynamic (like load user events, which would require to perform database queries)

Is there any existing brenchmark about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:  Do what is easier to code.  The performance difference is too small to matter.

I find it easier for static pages to be files.  And constructed pages built by PHP.  Sometimes I have 1 php file building 1 page.  Sometimes I have 1 php file building many pages, usually minor variants on one page.  But then, I have to pass arguments to say which variant I am building.

Answer (score 1):

Without a more substantial description of your setup, the number of entries in each section/subsection, the kind of load, etc., noone can answer this question for you.

And really, except for some pathological use cases, noone should. You should answer your question with benchmark data from your implementation.

The only clear drawback I can see in the solution you describe with PHP files is code duplication, but that would be easily managed if you have some automated creation of the files.

Comment: There's no current implementation, and no current data, **that's the point**: design before have the problem. I'm asking about **ANY** brenchmark to start with.

Comment: I'm asking among, another things, apache loading the page vs. apache sending all request to a script wich will search into the database the page. Is there some miliseconds load from database vs. miliseconds load from filesystem for any implementation?

Comment: "*The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet.*" If you're trying to shave milliseconds in page load time of a design that hasn't started yet, you're doing something horribly wrong, believe me.

Comment: @Nowhereman what you are saying applies in case of over optimization. you should think of future problems before hands in design phase itself. You can rely on principle "we'll fix once it occurs". To prove this you might have read about "resolving problems after release is 200-2000x costlier than resolving in design phase". ESL I think you should find out usage pattern, no. of users using those pages, their distribution and then decide which one to choose. In my opinion DB should be used as it takes care of FS failure, backup, export, query support, caching etc. In FS that is manual task.

Comment: @NachiketKate, that was the meaning of my "*except for some pathological use cases*". So of course if they plan to have a few hundred thousands entries as PHP scripts in a directory, they should check if their filesystem handles very large numbers of files well (some do, most don't). But you never shave milliseconds between two solutions at this point in the design and with so few requirements. So his question cannot (and should not) be answered…

Comment: Thanks @NachiketKate, your answer is the most useful, but also thanks Nowhereman. I have to choose one of the two for start (and maybe change it later if create problems); and it is a particular system, so no previous data. I like general solution of Nachiket, as a start I will use database for most pages (except some mostly static), and later improve it on the go.

Comment: I known the "make it work, make it right, make it fast" adagio, @Nowhereman; but it's almost the same effort make it work with DB or FS. So, instead of throwing a coin, I ask for what have generally better performance as a starting point.

Comment: Glad I was helpful :)